# Solving Summation Equations for Method of Moments Proof

Tags: statistics, summation

A part of the solution in a proof of a question related to the method of moments states that,

$$\frac{1}n\sum_{i=1}^n{(y_i-\bar{y})^2}=\frac{1}n\sum_{i=1}^n{y_i^2-\bar{y}^2}$$

How does this follow?

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $(y_i-\overline{y})^2=y_i^2-2y_i\overline{y}+\overline{y}^2$. Summing the middle term and dividing by n will result in:

$2\overline{y}(\sum y_i)/n=2\overline{y}\overline{y}=2\overline{y}^2.$

Can you complete it from here?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the hint,

$$\frac{1}n(\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\bar{y}\sum_{i=1}^ny_i+n\bar{y}^2)=\frac{1}n\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\bar{y}^2+\bar{y}^2$$

Finally,

$$\frac{1}n\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-2\bar{y}^2+\bar{y}^2=\frac{1}n\sum_{i=1}^ny_i^2-\bar{y}^2$$